# GridLayout in Recyclerview width and height

Tags: android

**This is my grid item xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/griditem">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/name"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/date"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**recyclerview in fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/recentView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Recycleview config in kotlin:**

```
recentView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context,2)
```

**My Layout output:**

[image]

**I dont want the extra space above and below my imageview**

Comment: which image are you addressing?

Comment: there are two images in the screenshot. (two grid items). The image view height is large. I dont want the extra space

Comment: Your saying about the profile image?

Comment: yes - the two images that is displayed in my recyclerview's grid layout are actually contact images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### try this

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle"/>
```

Comment: This worked. I typed adjustViewBounds = "true" and the imageview adjusted itself with its parent view!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in ImageView

Comment: It didn't work. Instead, the image view's proportions became abnormal (the extra space is now filled with the image)